# 80; Connection refused

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to post `tar` archive from one remote server to another, but while I execute the command

```
curl --user "root:$password" -X POST -T archive.tar ip-address
```

I get

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to ip-address:80; Connection refused
```

What should I change at `ip-address` server to open `80` either `8080` ports?

These ports are not in `listen` state while I execute `netstat -atpn`

Comment: Are 80 and 8080 ports should be listened by additional software I need install firstly?

Comment: No. You need to install a web server like Apache2 to listen on 80 or 8080. Even with it installed, it won't accept file uploads or POST without additional software. You probably want to install a SSH server, then use `scp` on the client to upload the file

Comment: @DanielT `scp` worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielT Yep. It looks like I have even already read it..

Comment: @DanielT Would my current question enabled by search engines either it would be removed?

Comment: Duplicates (at least those that are not downvoted) are usually not removed because they serve a signposts (such as for search engines) towards the canonical question. I find it strange that you found something that told you to use a curl with POST to transfer files. Which website told you to do that?

Comment: @DanielT I don't remember.
I just have always download the files from dumpfile to several different hosts, so now I was need to upload my files and found such way.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way to transfer files between the servers is
`scp file_path user@server_ip:path`